# Convolution on c++

Tags: c++, convolution, graphical-programming

I'm trying to implement a convolution function in c++. When I use it, it either crashes my program, or it convolves but it shifts my pixels.

```
for (int y = 1; y < m_imageHeight - 1; y++)
{
    for (int x = 1; x < m_imageWidth - 1; x++)
    {
        float sumRed = 0, sumGreen = 0, sumBlue = 0;

        // Applying the filter
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < cols; l++)
            {
                int posImage = ((y - 1 - k) * m_imageWidth + (x - 1 - l)) * 3;
                sumRed += m_copyImage[posImage] * filter[k][l];
                sumGreen += m_copyImage[posImage + 1] * filter[k][l];
                sumBlue += m_copyImage[posImage + 2] * filter[k][l];
            }
        }

        // Clamps the result
        sumRed = std::max(std::min(sumRed, 255.0f), 0.0f);
        sumGreen = std::max(std::min(sumGreen, 255.0f), 0.0f);
        sumBlue = std::max(std::min(sumBlue, 255.0f), 0.0f);

        // Updates the pixel on the original image
        int pos = (y * m_imageWidth + x) * 3;
        m_myImage[pos] = static_cast<unsigned char>(sumRed);
        m_myImage[pos + 1] = static_cast<unsigned char>(sumGreen);
        m_myImage[pos + 2] = static_cast<unsigned char>(sumBlue);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your tools support them, turn on the address and undefined behaviour sanitizers. These add extra runtime checking and will print out diagnostics describing exactly what went wrong and where, leaving only how to fix it up to you. On a GCC or GCC-like compiler you'd turn on the sanitizers with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`.

Comment: watch out with stuff like `(x - 1 - l` the similarity between `1` and `l` can result in some really hard-to-spot mistakes. Better to give the 1-letter variables longer, more descriptive names to avoid this and other common problems.

Comment: Recommendation: Make a [mre] (MRE} that feeds in an input set that triggers the crash. The crash and the broken  output are often two faces of the same bug and the crash is a lot easier to trap and investigate. If making the MRE doesn't end prematurely because it leads you to the solution, the usual result, replace the code in the question with the MRE.

Comment: Carefully investigate the values of `posImage` and `pos` because these are the most common points of failure. Look at them with a debugger (when the program crashes, the debugger halts and allows you to inspect the crash site) or print them out and make sure they (and stuff like `pos + 2`) never exceed the valid range.

Comment: Going by the "border" of 1 (bounds of the outer two loops) and the `- 1` when indexing into the image, the kernel is supposed to be 3x3. Was this supposed to work for other kernel sizes?

Comment: You haven't given information about what the arrays (vectors? some other containers?) are in that code or - since elements are being accessed using array syntax - what the relevant dimensions are.    The innermost loop accesses `m_copyImage[posImage]` ... `m_copyImage[posImage + 2]` and `filter[k][l]` and the outer pair of loops modify `m_myImage[pos]` ... `m_myImage[pos + 2]`.    One OR MORE of those indices are probably going out of range, and causing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't code in C++, so take this with a grain of salt, but: could the issue be your for loops for `rows` and `cols`? I'm guessing they are what convolute your image, and them starting at 0 is probably what is shifting your pixels. This is because starting at zero for each loop takes points in a rectangle with the target point being the corner rather than the center. Starting at `-rows / 2` and `-cols / 2` or something of the sort would fix that issue.

Additionally, regarding the crashing, I believe that it because of accessing memory outside your image. This would happen if `rows` or `cols` causes your program to look for pixels beyond the given amount of your image. Fix this by adding guards that skip the loop if `y + k` ends up being larger than your image height and vice versa.

Edit: In short, dividing by two helps center the convolution rectangle around the center point. Let's look at an example, with starting at 0. In this example, let's just look at `cols`, and say that `cols` is 5. `+` will represent each column, while `0` will represent the target point.

```
    + + + + +
    0
```

As you can see, starting at 0, we have the columns extend way past the target point, with nothing before it. Now, we will start `-cols / 2` before the target point, which is equal to -2.

```
+ + + + +
    0
```

So, by starting the columns at this point, we effectively make it centered around the target point. The same applies for the rows.

Comment: It actually worked, thank you very much. But can you give me a further explanation on the reason it is divided by 2?

Comment: I'll put the response to this as an edit in the answer itself